# When passing gmock object as reference the setup expectations doesnt match

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock, otl

I want to test the behaviors of the following class.

```
class DAO{
    otl_connect *conn;
    public:
        DAO(otl_connect* _conn){
            conn = _conn;
        }

        bool init(){
            bool ret = true;
            try{
                conn->rlogon("ABC");
            }catch(otl_exception &e){
                ret = false;
            }
            return ret;
        }
};
```

To do that I created a derived mock class from otl_connect;

```
class MockOtlConnect : public otl_connect {
    public:
        MOCK_METHOD0(logoff, void());
        MOCK_METHOD1(rlogon, void(const char *connect_str));
};
```

In my test it is created an expectation to the function call `rlogon`

```
TEST(TesteMockOtlConnect, MockingOtlConnect){
    MockOtlConnect mock;
    EXPECT_CALL(mock, rlogon("ABC"));

    DAO dao(&mock);
    EXPECT_TRUE(dao.init();
}
```

But this expectation never get satisfied.

```
Actual function call count doesn't match EXPECT_CALL(mock, rlogon("ABC"))...
         Expected: to be called once
           Actual: never called - unsatisfied and active
```

Comment: Mocked methods must be `virtual`, there's nothing to indicate that they are `virtual` in [this documentation](http://otl.sourceforge.net/otl3_connect_class.htm). Either wrap it all in your own wrapper class with virtual methods, or read chapter about mocking non-virtual methods in GoogleMock [cookbook](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/release-1.10.0/googlemock/docs/cook_book.md#mocking-non-virtual-methods-mockingnonvirtualmethods)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is wrong matcher. By writing:

```cpp
EXPECT_CALL(mock, rlogon("ABC"));
```

You are not expecting call of `rlogon` with a string `"ABC"`, but you are expecting call with some pointer value which you do not have control over it.
Reason is that your argument type of is `const char *`

To fix it use `StrEq()` matcher.

```cpp
EXPECT_CALL(mock, rlogon(StrEq("ABC")));
```

Comment: I gues the issue could be both, same output is printed when a non-virtual function is called and when it couldn't match arguments (although the latter also provides info what expectations were tried). https://godbolt.org/z/c1f78G8re